# Casting and Melting with reshape in R

Tags: r, reshape

As an example let's say that I have the following dataframe:

```
datas=data.frame(Variables=c("Power","Happiness","Power","Happiness"),
Country=c("France", "France", "UK", "UK"), y2000=c(1213,1872,1726,2234), y2001=c(1234,2345,6433,9082))
```

Resulting in the following output:

```
  Variables Country  2000  2001
1 Power     France   1213  1234
2 Happiness France   1872  2345
3 Power     UK       1726  6433
4 Happiness UK       2234  9082
```

I would like to reshape this dataframe as follows:

```
  Year      Country  Power Happiness
1 2000      France    1213      1872  
2 2001      France    1234      2345
3 2000      UK        1726      2234
4 2001      UK        6433      9082
```

I started out with:

```
q2=cast(datas, Country~Variables, value="2000")
```

But then got the following error:

```
Aggregation requires fun.aggregate: length used as default
Error in `[.data.frame`(sort_df(data, variables), , c(variables, "value"),  : 
  undefined columns selected
```

Any suggestions?
Also: Would it matter for the solution that my dataframe is really big (417120 by 62)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you're interested in a `tidyverse` alternative

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    gather(Year, val, -Variables, -Country) %>%
    spread(Variables, val)
#  Country Year Happiness Power
#1  France 2000      1872  1213
#2  France 2001      2345  1234
#3      UK 2000      2234  1726
#4      UK 2001      9082  6433
```

Or using `reshape2::melt` and `reshape2::dcast`

```
reshape2::dcast(
    reshape2::melt(df, id.vars = c("Country", "Variables"), variable.name = "Year"),
    Country + Year ~ Variables)
#        Country Year Happiness Power
#1  France 2000      1872  1213
#2  France 2001      2345  1234
#3      UK 2000      2234  1726
#4      UK 2001      9082  6433
```

Or (identically) using `data.table::melt` and `data.table::dcast`

```
data.table::dcast(
    data.table::melt(df, id.vars = c("Country", "Variables"), variable.name = "Year"), 
    Country + Year ~ Variables)
#  Country Year Happiness Power
#1  France 2000      1872  1213
#2  France 2001      2345  1234
#3      UK 2000      2234  1726
#4      UK 2001      9082  6433
```

In terms of performance/runtime, I imagine the `data.table` or `tidyr` solutions to be the most efficient. You can check by running a `microbenchmark` on some larger sample data.

---

### Sample data

```
df <-read.table(text =
    "  Variables Country  2000  2001
1 Power     France   1213  1234
2 Happiness France   1872  2345
3 Power     UK       1726  6433
4 Happiness UK       2234  9082", header = T)
colnames(df)[3:4] <- c("2000", "2001")
```

---

### Benchmark analysis

Following results from a `microbenchmark` analysis of the four methods, based on a (slightly) larger `78x22` sample dataset.

```
set.seed(2017)
df <- data.frame(
    Variables = rep(c("Power", "Happiness", "something_else"), 26),
    Country = rep(LETTERS[1:26], each = 3),
    matrix(sample(10000, 20 * 26 * 3), nrow = 26 * 3))
colnames(df)[3:ncol(df)] <- 2000:2019

library(microbenchmark)
library(tidyr)

res <- microbenchmark(
    reshape2 = {
        reshape2::dcast(
            reshape2::melt(df, id.vars = c("Country", "Variables"), variable.name = "Year"),
            Country + Year ~ Variables)
    },
    tidyr = {
        df %>%
            gather(Year, val, -Variables, -Country) %>%
            spread(Variables, val)
    },
    datatable = {
        data.table::dcast(
            data.table::melt(df, id.vars = c("Country", "Variables"), variable.name = "Year"),
            Country + Year ~ Variables)
    },
    reshape = {
        reshape::cast(reshape::melt(df), Country + variable ~ Variables)
    }
)
res
#Unit: milliseconds
#      expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#  reshape2  3.088740  3.449686  4.313044  3.919372  5.112560  7.856902   100
#     tidyr  4.482361  4.982017  6.215872  5.771133  6.931964 28.293377   100
# datatable  3.179035  3.511542  4.861192  4.040188  5.123103 46.010810   100
#   reshape 27.371094 30.226222 32.425667 32.504644 34.118499 41.286803   100

library(ggplot2)
autoplot(res)
```

[image]

Comment: `library(tidyr)` is sufficient.

Comment: Thank you so much for your very extensive answer. I would want to use the tidyverse solution as recommended but I have a bit of trouble reading the syntax. If I apply the tidyverse solution I get the error: `Error in is_character(x) : object 'Variables' not found` . Could it be that I first have to define which are the variables? Something like `Variables <- df[,2]` ?

Comment: @TomKisters `Variables` is one of the column names of your sample data. In `gather(Year, val, -Variables, -Country)` we turn data from wide to long, storing column names from all columns except `Variables` and `Country` in `Year` and values in `val`.

Comment: Sorry, that was really stupid haha. I tried it and it seems to work! Thank you so, so much. This helped me such a great deal.

Comment: You're very welcome @TomKisters and absolutely no need to apologise, we've all been there;-)

Comment: @TomKisters PS. I was curious, and added a quick benchmark analysis; it seems `data.table` and `reshape2` are the two fastest methods; however, the sample data is still small, so results might change for larger datasets...

Comment: @MauritsEvers I am trying to dig a bit deeper in the tidyr syntax. I tried to expand on your answer because my actual dataset has a few more columns.
`WDI<-WDI %>% gather(Year, val, -`Indicator Name`, -`Indicator Code`, -`Country Name`,-`Country Code` ) %>% spread(`Indicator Code`, val)
This however resulted in the following error: cannot allocate vector of size 284.8 Gb. Is there another way to add these columns using your general solution?

Answer (score 0):

As above, I would strongly recommend using `tidyr` instead of `reshape`, or at least using `reshape2` instead of `reshape`, as it fixes many of the performance issues with `reshape`.

In `reshape` itself, you have to melt `datas` first

```
> cast(melt(datas), Country + variable ~ Variables)
Using Variables, Country as id variables
  Country variable Happiness Power
1  France    y2000      1872  1213
2  France    y2001      2345  1234
3      UK    y2000      2234  1726
4      UK    y2001      9082  6433
```

And then renaming and converting the columns as necessary.

In `reshape2` the code is identical but you would use `dcast` instead of `cast`.  `tidyr`, as in @Maurits Evers's solution above is a better solution and most development has shifted from `reshape2` to the `tidyverse`